# Angular http.post as Options method request

Tags: http, angular, http-headers

I'm trying to post some data to node server, but I have an issue:

```
postEmployeeForm(employee: Employee):Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(employee);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3100/postemployee', body, options)
             .map(this.extractData)
             .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

This is my post request by in Network tab I see this as Options method while on server I'm expecting a post request.

If I omit options from http.post then I get post request on server, but then I have error about unexpected content type.

```
postEmployeeForm(employee: Employee):Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(employee);

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3100/postemployee', body)
             .map(this.extractData)
             .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Is this expected behaviour or I'm doing something wrong with post. I found this code on official angular guide: [server-communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)
How to handle this situation, do I need to change something on client side or should I handle that on server side?

EDIT:

This is my server code:

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require("formidable");
var util = require('util');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

    if(req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        console.log("Get request!");
        processForm(req,res);
        return;
    }
});

function processForm(req,res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields) {

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        });

        res.end(util.inspect({
            fields: fields
        }));

        console.log('posted fields:\n');
        console.log(util.inspect({
            fields: fields
        }));
    });
}

var port = 3100;
server.listen(port,'localhost');
console.log("server listening on port " + port);
```

Comment: What are the headers being set with `{ headers: headers }` ?

Comment: @GrishaLevit { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

Comment: What is the issue with first block of your code? It doesn't initiates a post request?

Comment: @Ali Baig Yes, it's instantiates a options request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on server side. You need to implement hanlder for options.
example:

```
app.options("*",function(req,res,next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get("Origin")||"*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   //other headers here
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.METHOD

Comment: Thanks, I don't use express but I implemented options method on server and it worked. It first put options request then post request. My question is is it expected to do that?